# TypeError: 'dict_keyiterator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, curl, pyspark

i try to learn this tutorial here 
https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/building-a-web-service-with-apache-spark-flask-example-app-part2-du1083854

using spark,flask i try to send file user_ratings.file with curl in win 10 using cmd with this line of code

```
curl --data-binary @user_ratings.file http://127.0.0.1:5432/0/ratings
```

the file have no format only this data

260,9 1,8 16,7 25,8 32,9 335,4 379,3 296,7 858,10 50,8

the function that post is

```
@main.route("/<int:user_id>/ratings", methods=["POST"])
def add_ratings(user_id):
    # get the ratings from the Flask POST request object
    ratings_list = request.form.keys()[0].strip().split("\n")
    ratings_list = map(lambda x: x.split(","), ratings_list)
    # create a list with the format required by the negine (user_id, movie_id, rating)
    ratings = map(lambda x: (user_id, int(x[0]), float(x[1])), ratings_list)
    # add them to the model using then engine API
    recommendation_engine.add_ratings(ratings)

    return json.dumps(ratings)
```

but it dont send any thin in csv file 
spark message error was

```
 File "C:\Users\ibrahim\Desktop\RSS\app.py", line 33, in add_ratings
    ratings_list = request.form.keys()[0].strip().split("\n")
TypeError: 'dict_keyiterator' object is not subscriptable
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Sep/2017:23:46:48 +0200] "POST /0/ratings HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "curl/7.55.1"
```

i seems this line in the function

```
 ratings_list = request.form.keys()[0].strip().split("\n")
```

in the tutorial it post data to csv file 
any help ,thank for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR You're using Python 3, while tutorial uses Python 2. You can try:

```
ratings_list = list(request.form.keys())[0].strip().split("\n")
```

Comment: Note: If the form might have a huge number of keys (so `list`ifying would be making a huge temporary `list`, only to discard all but the first entry), you can avoid it by replacing `list(request.form.keys())[0]` (where the `.keys()` isn't needed anyway; `dict`s are iterables of their keys already) with `next(iter(request.form))`; that makes the lazy iterator, pulls the first item from it, then ignores the rest without a temporary `list` being involved at all. Frankly, I'd use the latter form even if `request.form` is small, since it's a more direct solution.